# Steps to implement date range feature in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am evaluating Quicksight to use as a BI tool for our application. In that process, I created a simple bar chart that shows realized return on a stock for a specific period (X-Axis: Realized Return, Y-Axis: Execution Date). However, our requirement is to let the user select a  date range and display the realized return for that selected date range (on Y-axis). It would be helpful if someone can advise on the steps to implement date range feature on the charts in QuickSight.

[image]

Thanks,
Venkat

Tried "Parameters" to implement date range filter to the chart but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

- Select the visualization in QuickSight
- Open the "Parameters" view on the side bar
- Create a new parameter called "StartDate" of type "Datetime" with an appropriate default value
- Create a new parameter called "EndDate" of type "Datetime" with an appropriate default value
- For each parameter, click "Add control":

[image: Screenshot of the "Add control" button]

- Assign each control an appropriate name and date format
- Open the "Filters" view on the side bar
- Click "Add Filter" and select the field from your dataset that contains the date on which to apply the filter
- Edit the new filter
- Select the "Use parameters" checkbox
- Enter the "StartDate" and "EndDate" parameter names

[image: Screenshot of the StartDate/EndDate filter]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a date filter to the visualization.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/add-a-filter-data-prep.html

Once the filter is added to the visualization, you can also add it as a control to the Analysis/Dashboard to let the end user interact with it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/filter-controls.html